# Security surrounding ios app connecting to website

Tags: ios, security, authentication, web-development-server

Okay, this is going to be a really green question probably mostly about website security.

Okay so i have a website with a .xml file on it. The user should only be able to get to this website with some kind of authentication (because they bought access to it via in app purchase) I'm not asking for code or anything here, just what should i be looking into? It's not a dedicated server but just a plain old website (hosted one.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you can do, depending on where you wish to trade off effort and security.

1. **Key in URL**

This is the simplest solution. You merely add a random key to the URL of the XLS. For example: `http://yourserver.com/lirhmlihxiuhdgrmiurtokucdt/file.xls`

**Pro:** Extremely simple, will prevent random users from finding the XLS

**Con:** The link can be shared easily.

2. **Basic Authentication**

This is slightly more complicated. Depending on your implementation, you can keep the authentication credentials secret from your end-user.

**Pro:** Easy to implement.

**Con:** Basic auth can still easily be sniffed by a tech-savvy user.

3. **Custom authentication**

Create a login and session system that requires the application or user to authenticate. Give out individual credentials for each purchase.

**Pro:** Decent security. Relatively straight forward to implement.

**Con:** The XML file can still be shared. Other users may download the same files if an attacker manages to extract the credentials.

4. **iAP Receipt Verification**

Integrate the download of the XML into your iAP flow. Get the transaction token from the user and verify it on the server. Only if the purchase is legitimate, allow the XML file to be downloaded. Store the file locally on the phone for future access.

**Pro:** The most secure solution if you want to make sure the file is only available to paying customers.

**Con:** Relatively difficult to implement. However, the iAP guidelines contain good documentation.

What you need depends on where you want to trade off the time (and cost) it takes you to implement the measures with the expected loss of revenue from circumvented security.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much! It's not that sensitive data but i think i'll go with 4, just for the experience if nothing else!